# Show that the power series solution doesn't exist

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is

$$y' = e^{-1/x^2}, y(0)=0$$

I tried substituting the series solution (the usual way)$y = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty a_n x^n$ and then using the series expansion of $e^x$ to compare coefficients but that gives the following absurd equation

$$  \sum_{n=0} ^\infty a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!x^{2n}}  $$

I am stuck after this.

Can we directly say that since $e^{-1/x^2}$ is not analytic at $x=0$ so a power series solution cannot exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taylor series of $$e^{-\frac{1}{x²}}$$ at $x=0$ is the zero-function. Hence this approach would lead to the solution $y(x)=0$ which is not correct.